# Chrome CORS request sending two cookies with the same name

Tags: javascript, laravel, cookies, cross-domain

I'm in the middle of migrating an older perl app with a newer PHP version, based on Laravel. This requires the perl app to make XHR requests to the new Laravel app, and I'm having some trouble in Chrome with the cookies being returned.

When already logged in to both apps, I'm attempting to make two requests to the Laravel app: the first requesting a CSRF token, the second using that token to make a POST request.

I've configured CORS to the point where I am sending and receiving cookies fine, and the initial /token GET call works correctly (authenticates based on the cookie sent by the XHR request)

The /token call then returns a Set-Cookie header (as expected) with a laravel_session cookie, but my issue is that the following POST request is sending two versions of the same cookie, and PHP seems to only be looking at the incorrect one and thus loading the wrong session and testing against the wrong CSRF token.

Here are the details of all 3 requests - as you can see the final POST is sending two versions of the same cookie, with different values. (Line breaks added in cookie headers for clarity)

This only occurs in Chrome, in Safari it seems to send the correct cookies and the CSRF token is validated correctly. Chrome version is 45.0.2454.101.

Token Request Headers:

```
GET /token HTTP/1.1
Host: laravel.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */ *
Origin: https://perl.domain.com
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://perl.domain.com/original/page.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im5kSG02TVhsc08wUVZCZkd2WnZQa1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWFE0MXFBNlZIMnNXVHppXC9hN0dqNlJ2K1psUU9JZlFqTUdZZ3RJVmc0N1ZqV0MrVEczOGVFV0ExcDRDYmQxZDBTbFhGaWFiUkh5TGowOUgxdzVKOCtBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJhOTYzNDFlZjUyYTdjMWFmMDE1MTFlMjczYTA0NTE2NThlYjVlNTkyOWUyZWNjZWM1MGYxODc4MmVjMTM5YTFhIn0%3D;
laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImdSM0VTT25FUzZoY3JOeVwvN2JLWFFnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ilp3WHBFZlNuTnZibVMyMUlvbk1YM1YwdXF5VjRnTW1CNWVjUU1ReXlLZldSeEJxeTJFSmgyN2pyTjAydXlzMzE1TmJseWZrQmRraStDUkFqNTFReUp3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5MWMxM2YyNzFjOTY3ZjIxMmVjYmNlZWNlNDAzYjI2MjZkNmJhMzIyM2VlNTAwNGJlNTQ4OTU4OTMxZjJhYjE5In0%3D;
_ga=GA1.3.1924987937.1443461035;
_dc_gtm_UA-5119192-1=1
```

Token Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://perl.domain.com
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:40
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 17:24:18 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=80
P3P:policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa CUSa PSAa IVAa CONo OUR IND UNI STA"
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImFiT3ZSWWVDUnlKcWMraGFrWnBVY2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOTVnc05UM3puVGRwTUNUbDl3T1FNTVpWdGxVM29VaHNLSUt0XC9LTkhzMG5iOGlNbmhHXC9KMDBBTW9qRjZFQXZaSmlHTmhKUVpmTGdpXC80K0lkSUhUdnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjI5Njc1ZWE2NTRiYTY4NWJhMmE5Y2UwNjBlZDRkOWE4OGQwOWQ5NjE1YjAyNTMwNTFmZDczY2RjNzRiNjExNDIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 28-Sep-2015 19:24:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJqbTRyWG1GOEd1c2NIRnd4eE4yMGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZzk2SFE2emxcL0xGNjI3aGtYd1NmWURUVEduMVZVY2dYeUlRTVo2UTYyU0I2dFljalhxTjJSY3JFMGpvXC9nc2N0N3dJUFZYbGQya3pUNit1eWtrM3JqZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNDBhYzAzZjkwNDA5ZDE4Y2Y5ZjQ1MjdiYTUwYWU2M2Y5NjVjY2I1ZmMxZWFlMzAwZWM4MmVjNWRlYjM2Yjc2ZSJ9; expires=Mon, 28-Sep-2015 19:24:23 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
```

Preflight Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /destination/of/post HTTP/1.1
Host: laravel.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://perl.domain.com
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: https://perl.domain.com/original/page.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Preflight Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 17:24:24 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.readytoship.com.au
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: ACCEPT, CONTENT-TYPE
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImVRTGM3Q1I5RUttXC83NlVLNEN3Z3ZRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlE0SVRjVnJHRHhRUXFYYUhZbVwvSEpLSFp2VVZSa0creW5OUzR2aFdXTEI5VWFEMzBCSkNjeHBzR0dycjVuYWxsOVJ4KzdNVWhhR3dMSmhiam8yUDZcL1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImRiYzE4ODRlMTAyOTFkMmY0NTI2YjkzMmExMGZjM2EzOTU2ZDc3N2Q1ZGQzYjNhM2EyNDY5YjhjNGIxMjVlMWYifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 28-Sep-2015 19:24:24 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InR5M3JjWkltaVdoSldIa3FsWVp2YUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibjFuODdiVXRKQmdvU1hVcTdcL3VQeWF4K243d2h3Z3EwNWtVeTNWZUdBWGFWQ21QQXlid2RFSmNLSklpanVpZUNhZGE5UlU2Q1FqUCtnSVd4UWkwM2ZRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI1ZjNjOWQyNmZlNGI1MDI5OGQxOGY2ZGI5M2M1MTMwNWRjZGY4MDVjMGViODNjYjg0MmU5ZWQ0MzRjNjYyN2VhIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 28-Sep-2015 19:24:24 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa CUSa PSAa IVAa CONo OUR IND UNI STA"
Content-Length: 3501
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=80
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

POST Request Headers:

```
POST /destination/of/post HTTP/1.1
Host: laravel.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 72
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */ *; q=0.01
Origin: https://perl.domain.com
X-FirePHP-Version: 0.0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://perl.domain.com/original/page.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _dc_gtm_UA-5119192-1=1; _ga=GA1.3.2141864485.1441288526;
__zlcmid=WXevTAW8aGLGrO; 
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImQ1TFRGaWFwK3cyd3RRa3BzbUNmc0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNGEydmlLWE96NzZueWtaWWlUa3UzMjZOK29NbmNPb2VidVdVYzdSbkZsaWJMVmxBRitLT05oK3hodUc1ejRMOWJWYzVIeEl6UlpzQ0dIeWlob3pFOFE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjkzNTczMDJlOWVhZjM5NTU0NGEyNmE5YWNiODcxNDk4YmE0ODEyYTE3ZWExODBiMmNhNDFmMGFhMjVmNjhhYjgifQ%3D%3D;
laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkIrc3QzUk1iQnNEKysxOEg2UCtSbmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYXVDalVhaUpDMms3K3AwZFVLV0EyMDMwK25tVUQyYWw5c1MxTVRkZ0ZvVWpcL2lZUndubitsQ2VVMDF1UFcwNzNsR1doNG9TY2diMEhadHdXMEoxamt3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5MjE1NWE0MGNmMDgyYzhlYjBjMDUwY2JhOGYxNThjZTM0MjMwM2E3M2VjZjg1ZTgxMzIxZjE5OTkzZDEzZDhhIn0%3D;
_ga=GA1.3.1924987937.1443461035;
_dc_gtm_UA-5119192-1=1;
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImFiT3ZSWWVDUnlKcWMraGFrWnBVY2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOTVnc05UM3puVGRwTUNUbDl3T1FNTVpWdGxVM29VaHNLSUt0XC9LTkhzMG5iOGlNbmhHXC9KMDBBTW9qRjZFQXZaSmlHTmhKUVpmTGdpXC80K0lkSUhUdnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjI5Njc1ZWE2NTRiYTY4NWJhMmE5Y2UwNjBlZDRkOWE4OGQwOWQ5NjE1YjAyNTMwNTFmZDczY2RjNzRiNjExNDIifQ%3D%3D;
laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJqbTRyWG1GOEd1c2NIRnd4eE4yMGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZzk2SFE2emxcL0xGNjI3aGtYd1NmWURUVEduMVZVY2dYeUlRTVo2UTYyU0I2dFljalhxTjJSY3JFMGpvXC9nc2N0N3dJUFZYbGQya3pUNit1eWtrM3JqZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNDBhYzAzZjkwNDA5ZDE4Y2Y5ZjQ1MjdiYTUwYWU2M2Y5NjVjY2I1ZmMxZWFlMzAwZWM4MmVjNWRlYjM2Yjc2ZSJ9
```

POST Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 17:24:24 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: https://laravel.domain.com/auth/login
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa CUSa PSAa IVAa CONo OUR IND UNI STA"
Content-Length: 416
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

Two cookies in the same name maybe because they are in different path, when you edit the cookie, you have to specify the same path and same domain as you get in your token response headers.

Comment: I think this was possibly the issue, though none of the cookies in the headers I gave in my example have a path other than '/' so I'm not sure how they were getting set. The other difficulty was that Chrome devtools doesn't seem to show the path of cookies coming from a cross origin request. Anyway, I discovered a separate CORS issue that was also causing problems and seem to have got it to work.

Comment: Can you dump the cookies that your server received from server side by using `$request->cookie()`, I'd like to know which cookies your server received, because it seems nothing wrong with the cookie path and domain. Also I found that preflight request does not send cookies,  so laravel will set a new cookie, is there any particular reason that you need the request token part, why don't you just skip it?

Comment: I need the request token for CSRF, as I need to do a cross origin POST request to the laravel domain. I was unable to find out where those cookies were being set unfortunately, the auth problem turned out to be something else and I don't have the time to follow these cookie crumbs to their source.

Answer (score 1):

The extra cookies (`laravel_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN`) were not sent in the /token request. That suggests they don't have a path of `/`.

Also, the extra values do not appear in any of the `Set-Cookie` headers.
Some possibilities / things to investigate:

1. Your browser may have picked up the cookies by browsing directly to the laravel.domain.com.
2. The cookies were set by requests you did not capture.
   I can tell you from experience that using Chrome's built-in tools won't tell you the whole story.
   Try Fiddler (or an equivalent client-side proxy) to ensure you catch all the requests and responses.
   If you have access to the private keys of both sites, you can also use WireShark to capture and decrypt the raw data being exchanged.
3. The cookies were created by a prior session.

The `Set-Cookie` headers you show all have `expires` & `Max-Age` set.
This means they are saved to Chrome's cookie store.
You can examine the stored cookies by going to Chrome's `Settings`, click `Show advanced settings`, click `Privacy > Content Settings`, click `All cookies and site data...`.
Click on a domain and it will show a "button" for each cookie.
Click these to see the `path`, `expires`, etc. and possibly more importantly ***when*** the cookie was set.

Comment: use `chrome://net-internals` instead of F12 devtools is also a good option.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty here because it's likely the closest to what the actual problem was - the failed authentication was due to a separate CORS issue, and unfortunately I don't have the time to track down exactly where these two cookies were being set. Thanks for your advice!